# C# sorting 2 categories with bubble sort

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.IO;

public class Earthquake
{
    public string Magnitude { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
    public string depth { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string EventID { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public Earthquake()
        : this(string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty)
    { }
    public Earthquake(string magna, string locate, string lat, string longi, string dept, string dat, string Event, string website)
    {
        Convert.ToDouble(Magnitude = magna);
        Location = locate;
        Convert.ToDouble(Latitude = lat);
        Convert.ToDouble(Longitude= longi);
        Convert.ToDouble(depth = dept);
        date = dat;
        EventID = Event;
        URL = website;
    }

}
public class ManageData
{   
    public void getData()
{
    string[] text = File.ReadAllLines(@"Earthquakes.csv");
    foreach (string line in text)
    {
        string[] myColumns = line.Split(',');
        Earthquake earth = new Earthquake(myColumns[0], myColumns[1], myColumns[2], myColumns[3], myColumns[4], myColumns[5], myColumns[6], myColumns[7]);
        //here i want to put each data in the Earthquake class
    }
}


}
```

Essentially the csv file is  8 columns, so what I did was read the file by lines, and then create an array that stores each piece of data from a string separated by commas. What I want to do now is sort the data, first by magnitude, and then by depth using bubblesort.

Comment: Why does it have to be with the worst possible sorting algorithm?

Comment: Why do you want to use bubble sort? Assignment?

Comment: So what's your question?  What problem have you come across implementing the requirements that you've posted here?

Answer (score 0):

If bubblesort isn't part of the requirement and all you need is a sorted list then you can use LINQ.

Something like this should work.

```
public class ManageData
{
    public List<Earthquake> AllEarthquakes { get; private set; }
    public IOrderedEnumerable<Earthquake> getData()
    {
        string[] text = File.ReadAllLines(@"Earthquakes.csv");
        foreach (string line in text)
        {
            string[] myColumns = line.Split(',');
            Earthquake earth = new Earthquake(myColumns[0], myColumns[1], myColumns[2], myColumns[3], myColumns[4], myColumns[5], myColumns[6], myColumns[7]);
            //here i want to put each data in the Earthquake class
            AllEarthquakes.Add(earth);
        }

        return AllEarthquakes.OrderBy(eq => eq.Magnitude).ThenBy(eq => eq.depth);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a problem with this answer other than it doesn't use bubblesort?

Comment: I got .. nothing. However, it might be beneficial to show an example using IComparer (e.g. with [List.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s.aspx)), should LINQ not be available as any value-based sort, implementation provided elsewhere, can trivially support IComparer ..